# How to upgrade iOS build to use the iOS 16.1 SDK?

Tags: ios, react-native, sdk

Testflight is sending out email with the following warning every time a new build is submitted. What needs to be done in order for the app to be built with iOS 16.1? Where can I specify the build to build with iOS 16.1 SDK? (Fastfile? Podfile? or Travis.yml?)

ITMS-90725: SDK Version Issue - This app was built with the iOS 15.2 SDK. Starting April 2023, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 16.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 14.1 or later.

After I upgrade the xcode to 14.2, I'm getting the follow build errors:

- there are no local code signing identities found.
- Maybe the error shown is caused by using the wrong version of Xcode

Comment: You just need upgrade your macOS version to 12.5 and Xcode version 14

Comment: I did, but getting build errors after the upgrade.

Comment: About that build error you got - what you should do with your code signing identities might be specific to your setup. You should read somewhere about how code signing works for iOS apps. You might currently also be using fastlane's `match`: http://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/

Comment: I was able to update to Xcode Version 14.3 (14E222b) even with macOS Ventura 13.0.